# getArgs string to int

Tags: haskell, args

I'm trying to write my first IO program in haskell, but I can't seem to run it from the command line
I want the command cabal run 5 > result.txt to print a 5 in binary in result.txt. I found some conversion code but when I implement it I get an error:

```
src/Main.lhs:23:28: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: [Int]
    • In the second argument of ‘writeFile’, namely ‘(toBin (args))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: writeFile "file.txt" (toBin (args))
      In the expression:
        do { args <- getArgs;
             writeFile "file.txt" (toBin (args)) }

src/Main.lhs:23:34: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[String]’
    • In the first argument of ‘toBin’, namely ‘(args)’
      In the second argument of ‘writeFile’, namely ‘(toBin (args))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: writeFile "file.txt" (toBin (args))
```

Here is my code:

```
module Main where

import System.Environment
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Map as M (Map, empty, insert, lookup)
import Data.Char (ord)

toBin:: Int -> [Int]
toBin 0 = [0]
toBin n = reverse (helper n)

helper:: Int -> [Int]
helper 0 = []
helper n = let (q,r) = n `divMod` 2 in r : helper q

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    writeFile "file.txt" (toBin(args))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**, your function `toBin` expects an `Int` parameter, but `args` is of type `[String]` - i.e. a list of strings. So you need to take the first argument (from your description) and convert it to an `Int`. The cheapest, dirtiest way to do that is with `head` to take first and then `read` to convert to `Int`:

```
writeFile "file.txt" (toBin . read . head $ args)
```

Note however that this code will crash at runtime if (1) the list of arguments is empty (i.e. doesn't have a "first" element) or (2) the first argument is not a number. If you're not ok with crashing, consider using safer alternatives, such as [`headMay`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.10/safe-0.3.19/Safe.html#v:headMay) or [`reads`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.10/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#v:reads).

---

**Second**, your function `toBin` returns a list of `Int`s, but `writeFile` expects an argument of type `String`. The cheapest, dirtiest way to convert is via `show`:

```
writeFile "file.txt" (show . toBin . read . head $ args)
```

However, the implementation of `show` for lists will yield a string that doesn't look like a binary number. It will look like `"[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]"`. If you're not ok with this representation, you will have to write your own function for converting the list to a string that looks like a binary number. The cheapest, dirtiest way of doing that is by applying `show` to each element of the list and then gluing the resulting strings together:

```
binToStr :: [Int] -> String
binToStr = concat . map show

...

writeFile "file.txt" (binToStr . toBin . read . head $ args)
```

Or it could be simplified to `concatMap`:

```
binToStr = concatMap show
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. What if I wanted to take multiple integer inputs like 5 45 28?

Comment: Then convert each element of the `args` list to an integer

Comment: would I have to use iterate to do that?

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: ...and try to figure it out yourself first -- for example, by consulting a tutorial and some documentation -- before making an additional post. All of your questions so far have been very, very basic, and there's a lot of very basic material out there to consume.